# how to receive gzip data ? Node.js

Tags: node.js, get, gzip

I'm trying to retrieve data from KEEPA about Amazon's products.

I'm straggling to receive the data in proper JSON format, as KEEPA sending the data as gzip.

I tried to used 'decompressResponse' module which helped to get the data as JSON but it was received multiple times on each call.

As the code appears below I'm just getting a huge Gibberish to my console.
Let me know what am I missing here, or if you have a better suggestion please let me know.
Thanks

```
const express = require("express");
const https = require("https");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");


const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.get("/", function(req, res) {

res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});

app.post("/", function(req, res) {


const query = req.body.asinId;
const apiKey = "MY_API_KEY";
const url = "https://api.keepa.com/product?key=" + apiKey + "&domain=1&asin=" + query;

const options = {
methode: "GET",
headers: {
"Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
"Accept-Encoding":"gzip"
  }
 }

https.get(url,options,function(res) {
console.log(res.statusCode);
console.log(res.headers);
var data;

res.on("data", function(chunk){
if(data){
data = chunk;
} else {
data += chunk;
}

console.log(data);
});
});

res.send("server is running");

});


 app.listen(3000, function() {
 console.log("server is running on port 3000");
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well the output function was wrong .. the correct one below

```
https.get(url,options,function(response) {
response = decompressResponse(response);
console.log(res.statusCode);
console.log(res.headers);
let data = '';

response.on("data", function(chunk){
data += chunk;
});

response.on("end",function(){
console.log(data);
});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the built-in `zlib` module with `gunzip()`?

```js
zlib.gunzip(data, (error, buff) => {
  if (error != null) {                                       
      // An error occured while unzipping the .gz file.
  } else {                                                    
    // Use the buff which contains the unzipped JSON.

    console.log(buff)
  }
});
```

Full example with your code: https://www.napkin.io/n/7c6bc48d989b4727

Comment: Thanks for your answer Thomas, unfortunately, I'm still receiving Gibberish with the example above.